# Dynamics AX 2012 Label File Problems

Tags: axapta, label, dynamics-ax-2012

We're having pretty consistent problems with one of our label files in AX 2012.

Boot up the server, the custom labels are not recognized.  The label file is still in the AOT, and everything appears to be in order, however, none of the labels will work until the .ald file is re-imported.  The labels will work as long as AX is left running.  Reboot the server, and the labels stop working again until re-imported.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Can you try to stop the AOS, delete the .ALI files (application label index) and restart? The ALI files would then be recreated from the label files

Comment: We'll give that a shot.  Will probably take a couple days before we can be sure if it works.  The problem recurs on a semi-regular basis.  Thanks.

Comment: In what Model are your custom labels located? Are you overriding labels from a lower layer?

Comment: We have two custom label files in the isv layer.  Neither override anything.  One works fine, the other one drops--just on one server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exported the ALD file.  Deleted it from the AOT.  Re-imported it.  Moved it back into the model store.  Seems to be working now.

Comment: Link - How to delete label file
http://yasirnedian.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/how-to-delete-label-file-in-dynamics-ax.html

Comment: Hm. If it comes up again it might be worth checking if there is a hotfix available.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'm wrong, but I think the labels are stored in the model store now? ald files I think are only used with source control integration and for importing

are the labels part of a model?

Comment: You are correct.  Labels files are stored in the model now.  However, one of our servers keeps dropping the label object until we re-import it from the old ald file.